# Calling javascript function from highcharts plotOptions

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to call a function from plotoptions of highcharts i tried like this but its throwing error

```
plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    events: {
                        legendItemClick: function(event) {
                        //iam trying to call a function here
                        sampletest(testArr);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

is this possible..how to call another function from plotOptions.

the error iam getting is

> TypeError: d is undefined

Comment: thats type error..it is TypeError: d is undefined

Comment: Can you post the code for your sampletest function ? It is possible that the error is in that function rather than in the legendItemClick function.

Comment: I Went wrong in the sampletest function only..at the end its building again the chart..thats the reason iam getting error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a IIFE for that.
This example is when the function y external of the chartOption{}

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        point: {
            events: {
                click: (function (integrator) {
                    return function (e: any) {
                        integrator.externalFunction()
                    }
                })(this)
            }
        }
    }
}

function externalFunction() {
    console.log('Prueba funcion externa');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can call any function from plotoptions events. Highcharts allows us to do so. just check the scope of that function

Comment: thanks for reply strikers..what should be the scope of the function?

Comment: What do you mean by _"check the scope of that function"_? A JS function has its own scope. if you mean context than: why would you have to check the scope? just `Bind` if needs must

Answer (score 0):

Please take look at example http://jsfiddle.net/gF8Cf/3/

```
    $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                events: {
                    click: function(event) {
                       custom();
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
        }]
    });

    function custom(){
        alert('aaaa');
    }
});
```